How to Analyze the Effect of a Dopant Atom on the Band Gap Using Supercell and Band Structure Calculations?
I want to study the impact of a dopant atom on the band gap of a material.
For a 2x1x1 supercell, is it necessary to perform band unfolding especially when I study the undoped in a similar super cell?

+1. Welcome to our community.

Please, take a look here.

Unless you wanna compare the band structure (BS) of a supercell with a BS of a primitive cell, you don't need the unfolding. As long as you want to know the effect of the band gap only, you don't need unfolding. Unfolding a BS will have no effect on the band gap. If it has a direct band gap, you can get that info from scf only. No need to get the BS. Just take a look at the energy values and the corresponding occupation numbers at the k-point where the VBM and the CBM are located. You might want to provide some detail about your material and the code you are using to get a detailed answer.

if you want a way to 'plot' the results, calculate and plot density of states. vanishing density of states at the fermi level is an insulator. non-vanishing =  metal. you can directly compare DoS to pristine primitive cell etc. assuming the kpts are convergend and DoS is appropriately normalized.
